# Docker containers: curl between containers not working

Tags: curl, networking, docker, ports

I have multiple docker containers in the same network. I am trying to use curl on containerA to get the result from an API on test01.docker container .

I run this command on container A:

```
curl -s test-01.docker:8031/app?status -v
```

The output is as follows:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 172.19.0.24...
* connect to 172.19.0.24 port 8031 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to test-01.docker port 8031: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
```

When I try to ping test01.docker from containerA using the following command:

```
ping test-01.docker
```

It is successful.

When I do docker ps, It shows the following information. In my

```
43823212be7e        mytestimage        "/docker-entrypoint.s"   53 seconds ago       Up 47 seconds       22/tcp, 2812/tcp, 5060-5061/tcp, 6970-6971/tcp, 8002/tcp, 8030-8031/tcp, 8033/tcp, 8071/tcp, 8888/tcp, 9020-9023/tcp   containerA
```

This shows that port 8031 is exposed. I'm unable to figure out why curl is failing on this. When I run following command on test-01.docker, it gives me correct output:

```
curl -s localhost:8031/app?status
```

Not sure why its not working from other containers in same network. Please tell me if I'm missing something.

Update: My docker-compose file looks like this:

```
  version: '2'

  services:
    test-01.docker:
      image: ##############
      expose:
        - 22
        - 2812
        - 8031
      hostname: test-01
      domainname: docker
```

Comment: Simply because the docker container is *not* in fact listening on port 8031 on your internal docker network. The port 8031 is exposed to your host machine, via a different interface than the one the docker containers use to communicate with one another.

Comment: Are you able to share Dockerfiles / docker-compose.yml ?

Comment: @ffledgling How can I make the port 8031 exposed to my host machine via the same interface that's used by docker containers?

Comment: @clever_bassi as JHarris said, please give us more information about your application and your docker setup. What is the app? How is it configured? What is your docker configuration?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that the app running inside test-01.docker listen on a 127.0.0.1, so it can not be accessed by any other programs outside this container

let your app(inside test-01.docker) listen on 0.0.0.0 address and try it again

Comment: you are right. this is the issue. how can I change it to listen on 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: that is not the business about docker, I think I need to know what the app is before I tell you how to